# Why is there a limit to the number of characters in the title of a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, title, character-limit

Sometimes, I want to post a question on Stack Overflow and the error message will be the title of the question, but the error message is too long, more than 150 characters. Why is there a limit to the number of characters in the title of a question?

Comment: Why would you need more than 150 characters (personally I think 150 characters is too many)? The title is simply that, a *title*; it tells us very briefly what the question is about. You aren't one of those people that puts your entire email in the subject line and sends the body empty, are you..?

Comment: @Larnu, no, I said the error message would be the title of the question, but the error message is too long, more than 150 characters.

Comment: Why would you put the error message in the title? The error goes in the post in a quote block.

Comment: @Larnu because that question was about that error.

Comment: And that's why the error goes in the question body.

Comment: @Larnu I know, I'll change this habit.

Comment: The title is *the summary* of the question. It should describe what it's about. And making it too long distracts from providing *a summary*.

Comment: Some users try to squeeze the whole question into the title. The limit is to prevent that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because we don't need entire error logs in question titles.

Just a simple example:

### Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Printer.printString(Printer.java:13) at Printer.print(Printer.java:9) at Printer.main(Printer.java:19)

That does not make for a good title.
You can easily make your title shorter and more descriptive:

### NullPointerException when trying to do X and Y

The actual error message should be in the question's body, any way.

---

Now, there *could* be an argument to decrease/increase the allowed length, but I honestly see no strong reason to change this arbitrary limit to a different arbitrary limit.